# Which method is correct for calculating total deviance explained for boosted regression trees?

Tags: r, boosting, methodology, method-comparison

I have the following output from a boosted regression trees model and I would like to calculate the total deviance explained.

```
mean total deviance = 1.283 
mean residual deviance = 0.107 

estimated cv deviance = 0.212 ; se = 0.045 

training data correlation = 0.97 
cv correlation =  0.937 ; se = 0.016 

training data AUC score = 1 
cv AUC score = 0.996 ; se = 0.002
```

I have come across two methods to do this which give me a different answer.

1) `D2 = 1 – (residual deviance/total deviance)` [(Nieto and Mélin, 2017)](https://cyberleninka.org/article/n/699733.pdf)

With my results this equation is

```
D2 = 1 - (0.107/1.283) = 0.92
```

2) `D2 = (total deviance - cross validated residual deviance)/total deviance` [(Leathwick et al., 2006)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/224040414_Variation_in_demersal_fish_species_richness_in_the_oceans_surrounding_New_Zealand_an_analysis_using_boosted_regression_trees)

With my results this equation is

```
D2 = (1.283-0.212)/1.283 = 0.83
```

The paper for method 2 does not provide the equation in their text but it is clear given their model results (Table 3, pp.272) that this is how it was calculated. Also, there is a question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/201339/what-if-explained-deviance-is-greater-than-1-0-or-100) that discusses this method.

Which of these methods is correct?

Comment: Just to be clear, in the second equation, what is denoted as `residual deviance` is what, in the first question, is denoted as `total deviance`. Can you please clarify that these are meant to be the same (i.e. the total deviance)?

Comment: My apologies for the mistake. I have now edited my question.

Comment: Thank you for amending that. Good on you to catch that up! (+1) Please see my answer below for more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither of the two methods is "wrong"; they measure different aspects of the data-modelling aspects. That being said, I would have a strong preference on the  Leathwick et al. approach as it tries to explicitly account for sampling variability; ultimately it is a repeated cross-validation report of our performance metric.

To comment on this a bit further: On the one hand,  the Nieto & Mélin's approach aims to directly generalise the concept of coefficient of determination $R^2$, using the deviance residuals instead of the actual ones. It does not resample the data or anything similar, it directly reports the choose metric (here $D^2$) overall the whole data. This can potentially lead to unreasonably optimistic results *regarding the generalisation* of our model's performance. On the other hand, the Leathwick et al. approach aims to incorporate the sampling variability directly through the repeated cross-validation step. We estimate values of our performance metric using "unseen" data that were excluded during training. Note that the "optimistic bias" can be immediately seen in the Table 3 of the L. et al. paper, if we use the model residual deviance instead of the CV residual deviance. In that case for example the CV-generated $D^2$ would move from $0.600$ to $0.663$ for the case of a Boosted Regression Tree with tree size `5`. The sample size of your particular application is not explicitly stated. Nevertheless given it is not gigantic, reading through  the methodology presented in Beleites et al. (2013) [Sample size planning for classification models](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0003267012016479?via%3Dihub) is a good starting point to get idea of how to assess sample size consideration in a (multiple) CV procedure.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer, very helpful.

Comment: Cool, I am happy I could help.