# When is Training data correlation score too low when using boosted regression tree

Tags: r, boosting

I'm attempting to use boosted regression trees to look at the effect different fish groups have on coral using the dismo package in R following Elith 2008 and 2017

However the training data correlation and the cv correlation looks to be low, is there an acceptable cutoff I should be aiming for?

Using this code

```
testmodel <- gbm.step(data=brtdata, gbm.x = c(10:12), gbm.y = 13,
                            family = "poisson", tree.complexity = 5,
                            learning.rate = 0.0005, bag.fraction = 0.6,
                            max.trees=5000)
```

I get this result

```
fitting final gbm model with a fixed number of 3450 trees for jcount

mean total deviance = 19.611 
mean residual deviance = 13.077 
 
estimated cv deviance = 15.676 ; se = 1.432 
 
training data correlation = 0.58 
cv correlation =  0.409 ; se = 0.071 
 
elapsed time -  0.17 minutes
```

Comment: I haven't use BRTs of `family = "poisson"` however, I expect interpretation of the results is similar to `bernoulli`. Calculate the deviance explained to see how well your model is fitting the data, please see this [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/408119/which-method-is-correct-for-calculating-total-deviance-explained-for-boosted-reg)

Comment: Alternatively, you could try the `ggPerformace` function of the `ggBRT` R package which can help you assess how well your model is performing.